# How long can a background-image be?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a rocket on my webpage that flies from earth to the moon. For the background i was thinking of having 1 picture that looks like this: [background](https://gyazo.com/3ce15a35dcf376047ae3d33a286ce66a)
. I am pretty new to all of this so i don't know if it is possible with a big height and what quality the max is of the picture as background.

i was wondering how I can fix the resizing for the background so that it only focus on the width and not the height. I only want the width fully in the browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `background-size: cover;` will help you with some of it. But realistically you'd probably want to have smaller "slices".

Comment: Will it not put some of the background-image out of the browser with cover? And what do you mean with slices exactly? thanks for the reaction! @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: The actual size in `px` is irrelevant. You can tell the browser to keep it or to ignore it, you can display an image of any size at any size, without limits (within the technological boundaries, of course). You can distort it or keep its original size. In fact, anything you can think of... can be done. Now, in terms of size in `kb`, you might want to try to provide whatever effect you want with the smallest possible size, so people on limited connections don't need to wait 10 minutes to actually see the background image.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu okay that makes it much more clearer! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a div class call it bg for example:

```
.bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("image.png");   

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Now that we have set the div class we need to use it

```
<body>
    <div class="bg">
        /* place page contents here */
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `background-size: cover;` to full the background.

Comment: `background-image: cover` is **invalid**. You probably mean `background-size:cover`, which does not need `background-repeat:no-repeat` because it is technically impossible for a background with size set to `cover` to be repeated, because it's sized to *cover* the entire area of the element. I assume you meant `background: no-repeat 0 /contain;`. But it's not as simple as that. In order to display nicely a `min-height` might be required on the element. Probably `200vw` or so, considering the proportions of the image.